# opening alertbox from async after Async Method is complete

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have a method in my main activity that executes an async class which works fine, but when I put the alert box code inside it doesnt not work. I.E.

```
public void onGetStatus(View v) {

    new AsyncClass().execute();
}

}


class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String > {

    @
    Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {



        //TODO       


    }

}




protected void onPostExecute(String test) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(test);

    alertDialogBuilder.show();



}
```

When I try to execute the AlertDialogBuilder in the onPostexecture method of class it doesnt work, but if I copy and paste into the the method thats calling the AsyncTask class it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this** calls the current object which is Async. Do this :-

```
protected void onPostExecute(String test) {

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);//Put your activityname instead of MainActivity

alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(test);

alertDialogBuilder.show();



}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` to `new AlertDialog.Builder(youractivity.this)`